# Should I convert DTO's from API to Eloquent models?

Tags: api, eloquent, model, dto

I've built an API that returns various different types of DTO, in collections or singularly. I'm questioning whether I should map these records to some type of model upon receipt.

I'm currently building a Laravel client application that will consume this API. My client application has little or no database, and certainly has no domain model in the local database. I now find myself in a situation without any Eloquent models (or models of any kind yet in fact) and it doesn't feel right.

I need some sort of mechanism to query, sort & filter my collections of data. I also would expect to define some behaviour for records and perhaps apply some transformations for my presentation layer. I would normally expect to be doing these things in and around the Eloquent model pattern.

I found myself going down the path towards turning my DTO's into Eloquent models, possibly with the help of https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi. But I started to question whether turning data into objects that are so heavily bound to database/SQL operations is overhead I don't need, and would they even work as I expect. Worth bearing in mind that in the majority of my use cases (e.q. displaying readonly records) I can work with simple arrays.

Next idea was to build my own set of models, but not Eloquent ones. Perhaps with the help of a library that will allow me to query array type collections in a SQLish way. Or am I making a ton of extra work for myself in writing each of these?

So my question really is "Can it be assumed that a DTO returned from an API should eventually be hydrated into some sort of model?"